# pull / get data (studies and series) from dcm4chee server in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, dicom, dcm4che

I am working on a project and I need to fetch data from dcm4chee server. I have successfully configured the DCMTK library for iOS.

Now I want to pull data (studies and series) from dcm4chee server into local storage. Can any one suggest in which way I need to proceed ?

Any type of help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using WADO for mobile device connections: http://medical.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/pdf/part18.pdf

Other options are DICOM C-MOVE and C-GET requests.

Comment: Thank you, but how to create C-MOVE and C-GET request. I have read the document of DCMTK but its very poor. Can you please give me any tutorial link or any code snippets ?

Comment: http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/mod_dcmnet.html has tools that fulfill most of what you'd need. I'm sure you can pull down the source code for them and take a look if you need to modify their implementation.